# VBA For-Next Loop error - no syntax error, but no results either

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Is someone able to point me to any errors in my code, because the below doesn't return any syntax errors, however, it doesn't do what I need it to do either.

In short I have a dataset of 85 columns, which I would like formatted as prescribed below.

newtablecolumn and finalcolumn are integer variables which I have declared and assigned earlier on in the code. Currently newtablecolumn returns 44, finalcolumn returns 42 and so the final i value should be 42+44-1=85.

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To i = (newtablecolumn + finalcolumn - 1)
Columns(i).NumberFormat = "#,##0_ ;[Red]-#,##0"
Next i
```

As my title says, there are no syntax errors and the code runs, however, none of the columns get formatted.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you running the code with the sheet selected as you're not referring to a sheet in the code.

Comment: Should you use `For i = 2 To (newtablecolumn + finalcolumn - 1)` maybe?